# Matching typed data emitters with partial data consumers

Tags: c++, types

I want to generate abilities in a video game by mixing and matching **ability skeletons** which produce data with **ability effects** that consume them. An example of an ability skeleton is a projectile that, when it collides with something, emits the owner's location, the projectile position, flight time, and what it collided with. An example of an effect that would consume this data is "take a position, create an explosion at that point." Or "take two object IDs, and swap their locations." Any effect can be paired with any ability that generates enough of the right types of data (for example, an ability that generates no position data can't possibly make an explosion).

This idea extends nicely to creating interesting and varied projectiles. For example, if a colliding projectile outputs its flight time, position, velocity, owning entity, and the entity it collided with, that could support the following on-hit effects

- Explode (using position)
- Explode, but explosion radius/damage scales with flight time (position, flight time)
- Drag the object that the projectile hit in the direction the projectile came from (velocity, entity projectile collided with)
- Swap the location of whoever the projectile hit and whoever threw the projectile (entity projectile collided with, owning entity).

I think it's a neat idea, but have run into issues with typing this in a type-safe way that allows for easily randomly generating these abilities, while also being typesafe. Another complication is that an ability might generate two pieces of positional data, while an effect might only need to use one. So that requires some sort of interface class/argument binding tech.

My current solution has a class for each effect's type signature, and conversions between them. That's fine when your only type signatures are "position" and "entity", but scales poorly to matching an ability that generates (position, position, velocity, float) to an effect that consumes (position, float).

I've considered having producers emit generic string->object map blobs and relying on ability generation to make sure that effects are only matched with ability skeletons that generate the correct data, but that seems difficult to maintain and worse than having type guarantees.

Is there a typesafe and extensible way to do something like this?

EDIT: I've been playing around with the "generic string->object maps and rely on ability generation to make things work" idea. I made a type signature struct, storing info like {numFloats=2, numPosVectors=1}, then statically associate a type signature with each ability and effect. During ability generation, I then guarantee that each effect is matched with an ability that generates enough data of the right types. I also have an interface class that reorders/drops elements from the string->object map to present a uniform data type to the ability effect. I'm not in love with this solution, but it's working for now.

Comment: Could be just me, but I did not understand what you want to achieve. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I've made some edits to attempt to clarify both my intent and what I've done so far.

Comment: Some actual code in the form of MCVE would be handy